# Android Dev: Is it possible to develop on top of/customize the Contacts App?

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

This is a pretty niche question, I'm sure, but basically what I'd like to know is whether it's possible for a new app to modify the existing Contacts app in Android. For a (very) simple example, consider an app that allows you to color your girlfriend's contact slot pink, or highlight all of your family members. Simple things like that, to  change the appearance of individual contacts.

Note that I do not want to create a new Contacts app. This is obviously possible and has been done. I simply would like to alter, or perhaps customize, the existing native Android Contacts App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, unfortunately, if you want to change how the user accesses their contacts, you'll have to create your own app. There's no way to build upon Android's existing default contacts app.

Comment: Ah..that's what I was afraid of. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't done a lot of work with android, but I think we should slow down a bit before declaring this to be true. I know that a lot of developers do customized releases/ remakes of Android OS versions that can be installed onto rooted phones, so would one not be able to modify the core of the Android OS (the contacts app is likely in there) and make the changes? I don't know for sure if you can or not, but this is just an idea.

Comment: Well, it's possible to download the Android source, compile the whole OS with a modified contacts app, root your phone and install your own OS. But this is a lot of very technical work, would probably only work for your type of device and wouldn't be an app that you could put on the marketplace.

Comment: Yeah, I'm talking about the idea of installing an app or running a script that will go in and add on to your contacts app programmatically, not a manual rewrite of the original source code.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a small thing you can do. From ICS and up, if you notice, the People app has options to show availability of a particular contact in Skype, gtalk, facebook, etc. This is done by some kind of plugin mechanism, where each "contact provider" (to give it a name) could provide their info to the people app. (Im yet to find out completely how this is done).

What you could do is: create your own application which plugs in to the people app (like what skype, gtalk, fb, etc does) and give the status "online" to your selected contacts. Maybe you can even set some status message for these contacts (you can see G+ statuses on your contacts, so it should be possible). Not exactly as fancy as what you wanted to do, but somewhere there.